# "Terminated due to time out" error in C, Insertion sort?

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I am trying to do an insertion sort with below but I get an error of "terminated due to timeout". What could be the reason for it? I have  described prin function separately for Print.

Sample Input

```
6
1 4 3 5 6 2
```

Sample Output

```
1 4 3 5 6 2 
1 3 4 5 6 2 
1 3 4 5 6 2 
1 3 4 5 6 2 
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

void prin(int ar_size,int* ar);

void insertionSort(int ar_size,int*  ar) {
    int i=1;
    for (i;i<=ar_size;i++)
    {
        prin(ar_size, ar);
        int j=0;
        while(j<i)
        {
            if(*(ar+i) < *(ar+j))
            {
                int temp;
                temp= *(ar+j);
                *(ar+i)= *(ar+j);
                *(ar+j)= temp;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }


}

void prin(int ar_size,int* ar)
{
    int p;
    printf("\n");
    for(p=0; p < ar_size;p++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(ar+p));
    }

}

int main(void) {

    int ar_size;
    scanf("%d", &ar_size);
    //int* _ar=(int*) calloc(_ar_size,sizeof(int)); //Tried this and below    decleration but i get the same error
    int _ar[ar_size], _ar_i;
    for(_ar_i = 0; _ar_i < ar_size; _ar_i++) {
        scanf("%d", &_ar[_ar_i]);
    }

    insertionSort(ar_size,_ar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess it should be mentioned, that you are probably talking of some kind of online programming challenge.

Comment: Is the quote on the end of 6'th line a typo?

Comment: yes this is the link, https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insertionsort2

Also that error on 6th line is a typo.

Comment: Yes, worked correctly in a another code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `j` in `insertionSort` is only incremented inside that conditional.  It's likely that the program is looping forever inside the `while (j<i)` loop.